# Long Distance Temperature and Humidity Sensor for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware, temperature

Does anyone know of a good alternative to the DHT22 for temperature and humidity sensing on the Raspberry Pi?
The DHT22 works great, but the wire length can only be a few feet long before you start running into problems. I want to connect a temp/humidity sensor at about 15 feet away.

Comment: Have you considered posting your question at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ? It could give you faster/better results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of 1-wire sensors, for example temperature>DS18B20 humidity>DS2438 or some else.

You can read more about 1-wire specification [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/148)